# How to properly exit standalone Java Play Framework script?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am using Java Play Framework 2.3.7 and have a standalone script that uses `StaticApplication` and imports stuff into my database that I want am able to run manually using the `runMain` command.

Mostly, it works pretty well, but I can't figure out how to make it exit properly. If I try using a `System.exit(0);`, it returns this error message:

```
Exception: sbt.TrapExitSecurityException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "run-main-0"
```

If I leave out the `System.exit(0)`, I have to kill the process using `Ctrl+C` myself.

Anybody know what to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running a `StaticApplication` (or any `Application`) in Play, you can stop the `Application` that is currently running (there can only be one) by using:

```
play.api.Play.stop()
```

The `Play` object keeps a reference to the current running application, and calling `stop()` will shut it down by stopping all of its running plugins.